# Create data.frame with variable as tag

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create : `data.frame(colname=1:11)` by providing variable `x="colname"`, I've tried `data.frame(as.formula("x=1:11"))` but id does not work, what is `tag` in data frame ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) setNames**

```
setNames(data.frame(1:11), "colname")
```

**2) names<-**

```
"names<-"(data.frame(1:10), "colname")
```

**2a) names(...)<-**

```
DF <- data.frame(1:11)
names(DF) <- "colname"
```

**3) structure**  This one mucks with the internal structure and is not really recommended but has been added since it is possible to do.

```
structure(data.frame(1:11), .Names = "colname")
```

**4) dimnames**

```
as.data.frame(matrix(1:11, dimnames = list(NULL, "colname")))
```

Comment: (2) is the same as (2a) except for syntax.  When you use `names(DF) <- ...` you are really running `names<-` .